# Dynamic HTML ID with Bootstrap, Play framework and Scala templates

Tags: scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I'm working on an application with Bootstrap and Play 2 using Scala templates. I want to enumerate the ID of every row of *jobs* so that each row will map to a corresponding collapsed row that show more information. Below is my initial attempt, but so far it doesn't work yet. Any comments or hints on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

```
<tbody>
    @lists.zipWithIndex.map { case(elem, index) =>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="res@index" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td><!--Display elem--></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><div class="accordion-body collapse" id="res@index"></div></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Have you tried to build it as shown in http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse?

Comment: @fynn: Yes, I have. It works fine using one ID only. Using that, whenever I click on any row, it opens the expansion of the first row since they have only one ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from one of my projects, just do it in the same way:

```
@countries.byRegion.zipWithIndex.map { p =>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href=@("#collapse" + p._2)>
        @p._1._1 <span class="pull-right">@p._1._2</span>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div id=@("collapse" + p._2) class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        @data.programs.map { prog =>
          @if(prog.region == p._1._1) {
            <p>@prog.level</p>
          }
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

to make it work you have to make "dynamic" href's and id's: `href=@("#collapse" + p._2)` `id=@("collapse" + p._2)` in your case change `p._2` to `index`

Comment: Thanks @Alexlv, however attribute href is not available in a <tr> element. Do you think there's a workaround?

Comment: @KennyLewis check out html on [this site](http://pullmanapartments.com/) they have just what you need. Basically wrap each row in accordion